# Random 502.3 IIS - Bad Request (Frequency is high when we increase the POST request size)

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

We're working on a project and here are some details:

ASP.NET Core 2.1, MySQL, Entity Framework Core, Windows Server 2012 R2.

We have deployed it on IIS. When we are testing the side on local (IIS) network its taking a lot of data (up to more than 3 MB as well).

Though when we have deployed it on our testing server (over internet), it started sending us 502.3 randomly (with 800Kb of data) and frequency increase to more than 80% when we reach  2MB approx.

With postman, it saves the data and the frequency is really low. But while sending the request from mobile device (e.g iPhone - same request), server throws 502.3.

Please NOTE that our API does have images in the form of base64 and # of images may vary.

What is the recommended payload size of the post request (Rest API)?

We have increased requesttimeout of aspcore to 23 hours. Also, investigating through FailedRequestLogs:

We are receiving following:

[FailedRequestLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLaH6.png)
We have reduced kestrel server mindatarate setting along with some other's as well.

From the logs it seems while buffering request wasn't received properly/completely and request was forwarded for further processing.

A) It fails the authentication because bearer token wasn't read properly and it throws 502.3 bad request, request time out

Here are the logs:

```
2018-09-28T01:29:15.2053179-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://URL application/json 1140717 (ca22a1cb)
2018-09-28T01:29:15.2061784-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] "Bearer" was not authenticated. Failure message: "Authentication failed because the access token was expired." (48071232)
2018-09-28T01:29:15.2138975-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Authorization failed for user: null. (a4ab1676)
2018-09-28T01:29:15.2139666-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Authorization failed for the request at filter '"App.Filter.CustomAuthorizeFilter"'. (8b6446cb)
2018-09-28T01:29:15.2140926-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Executing JsonResult, writing value "Common.ResponseViewModel.ResponseOk". (7bb75e80)
2018-09-28T01:29:15.2143662-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Executed action "App.Controllers.MobileControllers.MobilePController.Contgroller (App)" in 0.5548ms (afa2e885)
2018-09-28T01:29:21.8587588-07:00  [INF] Connection id ""0HLH53A197K0J"" bad request data: ""Request timed out."" (86f1a409)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request timed out.
2018-09-28T01:29:21.8999019-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Connection id ""0HLH53A197K0J"" bad request data: ""Request timed out."" (86f1a409)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request timed out.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowFailed()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetResult(ReadResult& result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.IReadableBufferAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.ReadableBufferAwaitable.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ConsumeAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
2018-09-28T01:29:21.9000756-07:00 0HLH53A197K0J:00000001 [INF] Request finished in 6694.7905ms 401 application/json; charset=utf-8 (791a596a)
```

We have increased FREB as well in order receive all information.

```
[Route("v1/initialIntervention")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveInitialIntervention([FromBody] InitialInterventionSaveViewModel initialInterventionSaveViewModel)
{
    ResponseViewModel responseViewModel = new ResponseViewModel();
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            Patient patient = new Patient();
            new FieldMapper().MapFields(initialInterventionSaveViewModel, patient);
            responseViewModel  = _encounterManager.SaveInitialIntervention(initialInterventionSaveViewModel, patient, user);
            if (responseViewModel.Status == StatusCodes.Status201Created)
            {
                await _notificationManager.NotifyProvidersAndRep(patient.StudyCenterId, Messages.InitialInterventionNotificationMessage, user.Id, Request.Headers["Host"], (int)EncounterType.InitialIntervention);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (initialInterventionSaveViewModel == null)
            {
                responseViewModel.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                responseViewModel.Response = new ResponseError
                {
                    Error = new ErrorViewModel
                    {
                        Code = (int)ErrorCodes.InvalidModelStructure,
                        Messages = new List<ResponseMessage> { new ResponseMessage { Message = Messages.InvalidDataStructure } }
                    }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                responseViewModel.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                responseViewModel.Response = new ResponseError
                {
                    Error = new ErrorViewModel
                    {
                        Code = (int)ErrorCodes.InvalidModelData,
                        Messages = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => new ResponseMessage { Message = x.ErrorMessage }).ToList()
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        responseViewModel = new ResponseViewModel()
        {
            Response = new ResponseError().Create((int)ErrorCodes.ExceptionOccured, e),
            Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
        };
    }

    return StatusCode(responseViewModel.Status, responseViewModel.Response);
}
```

We're afraid that above source code never start execution. The reason why we saying this is because in the Failed Request Tracing, it's showing 60-70% Json (data) received and then it jumps from Request to Response with bad request and eventually (repeating) 502.3. It would be difficult to share full source code.

Comment: Please post the failing code so we can have an idea of what's going on

Comment: Do you have high concurency? I mean high number of requests? Do you use Oracles shitty drivers? (iirc they are sync drivers over async method, so doesn't really scale well. Try Pomelo MySQL EF COre Provider, it uses true async)

Comment: Also how fast is your servers internet connection or the one of the uploader?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can you please click on the FailedRequestLog given link. The remaining software logs are posted

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLaH6.png

Comment: @Tseng we not using oracle as mentioned we are using MySQL. Also, we tried to deploy it on three multiple server's A) our testing server which is not very good and it's RAM remain's at 80% all the time. B) We quickly also deployed it on Azure App Services (Free) and result is the same

We haven't deployed it on live/big server yet with multiple cores etc.

Comment: But what about the user's with low internet speed/rate they should be able to use the service as well?

Comment: @NaveedAnwar: I didn't asked if you use Oracle DB, I asked if you use Oracle's MySQL Provider (`Mysql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` package)

Comment: @Tseng my bad. thanks for re-submitting your comment. Yes, we are using oracle provider and not using pomelo one. But from the logs and detail's it seems that request wasn't even received properly/completely by ASPCOREMODULE. 

Thanks for mentioning pomelo driver's. I'll evaluate it as well.

Comment: Well thing is, if you have many requests, you may suffer from thread starvation and if I remember correctly the Oracles provider doesn't provide true async support, so each request that involves the Oracles MySQL Provider will block the thread. When you are out of threads, no new requests may be accepted until a thread becomes available. So I'd just try out the Pomelo driver as it scales much better on high request scenarios

Comment: I'll check with Pomelo driver. I'm pretty sure, there is only one request at a time because it's our testing server and we were the one's sending request. Although the request does posses base64 images (approx 20). The total size of the request was 2 MB around. We have tested with around half of the size of request as well but the issue is the same.

Comment: I asked you to post the failing **code**, not logs. Please read the comments you receive before answering them

Comment: @Tseng how about the same request works as well with less amount of data (images)? Is there any possibility that of request getting buffered at the server and at some point it stop receiving the request and forward whatever portion it has received which is obviously incomplete wrong json. That's why bearer is not recognized and finally it responds back with the 502.3 bad request.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry for not understanding it earlier. Earlier assuming you were asking about the HTTP status code. Now, we assumed you're asking about source code? In case if i'm still being stupid didn't share the right code, please do let me know

Comment: Any answer to the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to token expiry, we set 1 minute of token expiry.
Request was taking 1+ min due to internet speed which in result was giving us 502.3.

Though even if you set 30 min of token expiry and user sent the request at 29th minute of it the same issue can be experienced.

I'm marking this as an answer but would like your thoughts how we can solve problem explained in second paragraph above.